# addStyleDeclaration is not working in my 4.0 module

Tags: module, joomla-4.x, jfactory, jdocument, deprecated

I'm trying to insert inline css in a module and it's not working.

In one of my modules php files i have the following:

```
$document = Factory::getDocument();

// Add styles
$style = 'body {'
    . 'background: black;'
    . 'color: rgb(0,111,51);'
    . '}';
$document->addStyleDeclaration($style);
```

But the whole thing is just doing nothing. I googled and found some tutorials but even when I copy their solution it's still doing nothing.
Am I missing something or is this deprecated or different in joomla 4?

I would really appreciate some help. Thank you all in advance.

Edit: I tried it in multiple files and different modules but it just does nothing. Same With inline javascript and even with "`$document->addStyleSheet`" and "`$document->addScript`".

2nd Edit: I tried it in my templates index.php and its also not working there. So Either its a general problem or I'm doing something wrong.
But it recognizes the "`$document->addStyleDeclaration($style);`" because when I forgot to define the document it told me that I cannot call addStyleDeclaration on an empty.

Comment: Please give us more detail than "one of my modules php files".

Comment: Are you sure the CSS has actually been loaded, but the specificity isn't high enough? Might be something overriding your values

Comment: @mickmackusa I think it's hardly important because it should work in any php file thats included somewhere in a module.
But to be specific: I tried it in the tmpl/default.php and also in the [modulname].php

Comment: @Lodder No I've checked intensively in the webviewer but it's nowhere. I even tried to add an important tag but still nothing.
The style is just not coming through.